# Variance of Wishart distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, covariance

$X\sim W_p(I_p,1)$, i.e. $X$ is a  $p\times p$ Wishart matrix. 
For a vector $p\times 1$ $\beta$ such that $|\beta|=1$, 
$E(X\beta)=E(X)\beta=\beta$.
How do I get ${\rm var}(X\beta)$? 
Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: I'm inclined to doubt that the constraint $|\beta|=1$ will have any effect on the answer. $\qquad$

Comment: I have a vague suspicion that there's some slick way to do this but that I won't figure out what it is unless I go back to the basic definition of the Wishart distribution and do everything by crude brute force.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Michael. Actually, the answer is $I_p+\beta\beta^T$, but I don't know how to get it.

Comment: Well at least that answer has the right shape.  I.e., it needs to be a $p \times p$ matrix and it needs to be quadratic in $\beta. \qquad$

Comment: When $p=1$ then you have $X \sim \chi^2_1$.  In that case you have $\operatorname{var}(X\beta) = 2\beta^2$, not $1+\beta^2$. $\qquad$

Comment: When $p=1$, $I_p+\beta\beta^T=1+1=2$ because of $|\beta|=1$ constraint. Also ${\rm var}(X\beta)=2\beta^2=2$.

Comment: So that constraint was essential. $\qquad$

Comment: If $|\gamma| \ne 1$, then let $\beta = \gamma/|\gamma|$, so that $\beta=1$, and then, if $\operatorname{var}(X\beta) = I_p + \beta \beta^T$, we would have $\operatorname{var}(X\gamma) = |\gamma^2| I_p + \gamma \gamma^T. \qquad$

Comment: ${\rm var}(X\beta)=I_p+\beta\beta^T$ holds only when $|\beta|=1$. So you cannot plug in $\gamma$ instead of $\beta$ since you assume  $|\gamma|\neq 1$. Besides, what does $|\gamma^2|$ mean? It means $|\gamma^T\gamma|$? Anyway, thanks though.

Comment: I should have had $|\gamma|^2$, not $|\gamma^2|$.  I didn't just plug in $\gamma$ in place of $\beta$.  I was saying that if $$\operatorname{var}(X\beta) = I_p + \beta\beta^T \text{ when } |\beta|=1,$$ then $$\operatorname{var}(X\gamma) = |\gamma|^2 I_p + \gamma\gamma^T \text{ for } \gamma\in \mathbb R^{p\times 1}.$$

Comment: Your intention is just to remove the constraint, right? Anyway, I finally got to know how to solve this problem. Thank you, though.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with the special case $\beta = [1,\,\underbrace{0,0,\ldots,0}_\text{all 0s}\,]^T$.  Then $X\beta$ is the first column of $X$.  The first entry in $X$ has a $\chi^2_1$ distribution, so its variance is $2$.  The other entries are of the form $Z_1 Z_k$, where $Z_1,\ldots,Z_p\sim \text{i.i.d. } N(0,1)$ and $2\le k\le p.$  For those we have
\begin{align}
\operatorname{var}(Z_1 Z_k) & = \operatorname{var}(\operatorname{E}(Z_1 Z_k \mid Z_k)) + \operatorname{E}(\operatorname{var}(Z_1 Z_k \mid Z_k)) = 0 + \operatorname{E}(Z_k^2) = 1, \\[10pt]
\operatorname{cov}(Z_1 Z_k, Z_1 Z_j) & = \operatorname{cov}(\operatorname{E}(Z_1 Z_k\mid Z_1), \operatorname{E}(Z_1Z_j\mid Z_1)) + \operatorname{E}(\operatorname{cov}(Z_1 Z_k,Z_1 Z_j \mid Z_1)) \\
&= 0 + {}0 = 0, \\[10pt]
\operatorname{cov}(Z_1^2, Z_1Z_k) & = \operatorname{cov}(\operatorname{E}(Z_1^2 \mid Z_1), \operatorname{E}(Z_1 Z_k\mid Z_1)) + \operatorname{E}(\operatorname{cov}(Z_1^2,Z_1 Z_k \mid Z_1)) \\
& = 0 + {}0 = 0.
\end{align}
So the variance in that case is
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 \end{bmatrix} = I_p + \beta \beta^T.
$$
Cleary this applies equally if $\beta$ is any of the other members of the standard basis.  If $\beta$ is a linear combination of those, then use what you know about variances and covariances of linear combinations.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your time.